Is it possible to inherit type based on keyof template in typescript?
I was trying to do a little hack. I can see how for example DOM ts files map different element names to their types.
I was wondering if I could make it so that a type MyType extends a different set of fields based on what a string value is. This is my attempt:
interface MessagesToContentMap {
   "error": {message: string},
   "success": {result: number}
}

Now I want to inherit this in a general message, sort of backwards of what you'd normally do:
interface GenericMessage<KType extends keyof MessagesToContentMap> extends MessagesToContentMap[KType] {
    type: KType
}

The main intention behind is that I hoped Javascript would infer the message type for if statements like this:
const msg: GenericMessage<any> = {};
if(msg.type === "error") {
    // type system should know this is {message: string, type: "error"}
}

This already works with typeof, so I was trying to see how fat can I push it. However the code I made does not work, it will not hint anything except for type property. It does hint that property correctly with options "error" and "success".
I also tried this, which works but does not match the actual messages I will be receiving:
interface GenericMessage<KType extends keyof MessagesToContentMap> {
    type: KType;
    data: WorkersInternal.MessagesToContentMap[KType];
}

It still did require explicit cast too. Ie (testMessage as GenericMessage<"wrk">).data.

• I'm not seeing a [mre] here; could you provide an example with a declaration for msg we can copy and paste into our own IDEs to see what you're seeing? Right now we only have verbal descriptions of the problem, not code that demonstrates it. • Wild speculation is that you want a distributive object type like this but without test cases I can't be sure, so please [edit] to clarify.

"The main intention behind is that I hoped Javascript would infer the message type for if statements like this:" TypeScript (not JS, I assume that's a typo) already does this, if you just use a union type: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions

@jcalz What you created is exactly what I wanted, feel free to post an answer!

@Thomas Thanks, this is actually a great tutorial.

You're not really looking for a generic type; instead you want a discriminated union of the form
type Message = { type: "error"; message: string; } | { type: "success"; result: number; }

That will give you the narrowing behavior you're looking for:
declare const msg: Message;
if (msg.type === "error") {
    msg.message.toUpperCase();
} else {
    msg.result.toFixed();
}


All that remains is to compute Message from the definition of MessagesToContentMap so that you don't have to write it out manually.  Given
interface MessagesToContentMap {
    "error": { message: string },
    "success": { result: number }
}

you can write Message as a distributive object type (as coined in microsoft/TypeScript#47109) like this:
type Message = { [K in keyof MessagesToContentMap]:
    { type: K } & MessagesToContentMap[K]
}[keyof MessagesToContentMap]

The part in the middle,  { type: K } & MessagesToContentMap[K] is essentially the generic thing you were trying to make. You can't use interface extension to combine {type: K} with MessagesToContentMap[K] because the latter is not a type with statically known keys. But you can use intersection to get that behavior.  Note that {type: "error"} & {message: "string"} is equivalent to {type: "error"; message: "string"}.
Then this is wrapped with {[K in keyof MessagesToContentMap]: ⋯}[keyof MessagesToContentMap]. That's what makes it a distributive object type, where the result is the union of the part in the middle for each member K of the keyof MessagesToContentMap]. We're distributing the part in the middle over the union.  (This works by mapping over each property to a new object type and then indexing into that object type with all the keys, getting a union).
You can verify that the if/else behavior above is the same with the new definition of Message.  And now if you modify MessagesToContentMap, the Message type will automatically update.

Playground link to code
